# How to get a parameter list for all SQL Server extended stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Using `sys.all_objects` and `sys.all_parameters`, we can get a parameter list for "P" type stored procedures. But `sys.all_parameters` doesn't have parameter info for extended stored procedures.

Comment: You shouldn't put tag names in the title - which is why I removed it. Its already tagged, so shows up as the relevant technology.

Answer (score 0):

Extended stored procedures are a deprecated feature. You should convert them to CLR functions.

Here is how you can list the extended SPs:

```
SELECT
    SO.name AS [Extended Stored Procedure]   
FROM
    master.dbo.sysobjects AS SO    
WHERE
    (SO.type = 'X')
ORDER BY
    SO.name
```

and you can't list parameters of them in sql since they are not native sql server SPs.

Comment: Decent answer to a wrong question. Nowhere OP asks for objects' **permissions**.